# How does one find the PyQt6 version of PyQt5 class QAbstractTransition

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm trying to convert this PyQt5 example to PyQt6 but it has some modules that are not available through QtCore. I've been taking a PyQt6 class and working through examples but I'm not yet at the point where I can understand the documentation very well. I found qrand and qsrand in QObject. How can I find how or where to import QAbstractTransition? Could this be something that is not yet implemented in PyQt6?

```
"""https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/animation/moveblocks.py"""
"""
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QAbstractTransition, QEasingCurve, QEvent,
        QParallelAnimationGroup, QPropertyAnimation, qrand, QRect,
        QSequentialAnimationGroup, qsrand, QState, QStateMachine, Qt, QTime,
        QTimer)
"""
from PyQt6.QtCore import (QEasingCurve, QEvent,
        QParallelAnimationGroup, QPropertyAnimation, QRect,
        QSequentialAnimationGroup, Qt, QTime, QTimer)
# from PyQt6.   can't find QAbstractTransition
from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QAbstractTransition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstracttransition.html) has been moved to the new module called [`QtStateMachine`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtstatemachine-index.html) so ideally you should import it using `from PyQt6.QtStateMachine import QAbstractTransition`. Unfortunately PyQt6 hasn't implemented it (maybe it's a bug), PySide6 has instead.